# python comparing previous and next row value

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I've a data set, as below sample with column (C1).
compare value with the previous value in the same column and with the next value in the same column. Based on certain condition label the row.

```
 C1
----
 3
 2
 5
 3
 2
 4
```

Condition:

X is the current value
P is the previous value
N is the next value
First and last value to be defaulted to "0"

1. If x is Greater than P and Greater than N then it is labelled as "0":

   P < x > N = 0
2. P > x < N then X is "1"
3. P < X < N then X is "2"
4. P > X > N then X is "3"

Result to be stored is a separate column C2

Final Result:

```
 C1  |  C2
-----+-----
 3   |  0
 2   |  2
 5   |  0
 3   |  3
 2   |  1
 4   |  0
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe shift is the way to go here,

I start with creating the data frame and two columns, one shifted to display the next number, the other to display the previous number on the same row. I also create a blank column that we will enter your target into (C2)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([3,2,5,3,2,4], columns=['C1'])

df['P'] = df.C1.shift(1).fillna(0)
df['N'] = df.C1.shift(-1).fillna(0)
df['C2'] = np.nan
```

giving us:

```
    C1  P   N   C2
0   3   0.0 2.0 NaN
1   2   3.0 5.0 NaN
2   5   2.0 3.0 NaN
3   3   5.0 2.0 NaN
4   2   3.0 4.0 NaN
5   4   2.0 0.0 NaN
```

We then make the comparisons, drop the two shifted columns we made, and we're done!

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row.P < row.C1) and (row.C1 > row.N):
        df.at[index, 'C2'] = 0
    elif (row.P > row.C1) and (row.C1 < row.N):
        df.at[index, 'C2'] = 1
    elif (row.P < row.C1) and (row.C1 < row.N):
        df.at[index, 'C2'] = 2
    elif (row.P > row.C1) and (row.C1 > row.N):
        df.at[index, 'C2'] = 3

df.drop(['P', 'N'], 1, inplace=True)
```

This leaves us with:

```
    C1  C2
0   3   0.0
1   2   1.0
2   5   0.0
3   3   3.0
4   2   1.0
5   4   0.0
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
c1 = [3,2,5,3,2,4]
c2 = [0]
for i in range(1,len(c1)-1):
    p = c1[i-1]
    x = c1[i]
    n = c1[i+1]
    if p < x and x > n:
        c2.append(0)
    elif p > x and x < n:
        c2.append(1)
    elif p < x and x < n:
        c2.append(2)
    elif p > x and x > n:
        c2.append(3)
c2.append(0)
print(c2)
>>> [0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0]
```

I belive you got wrong the example output c2 list, with the conditions you gave the output is different.

Answer (score 0):

Use [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to create a new lagged column in your dataframe. Then you can easily compare the values of both columns in vectorised fashion (which is very fast) and store result in a new column.